# Rolle's theorem: if $f(0)=f(\pi)=0$ then $f'(c)=\tan(f(c))$ for some $c$.

Tags: calculus, rolles-theorem

Let $f$ be a continuous function going from $[0, \pi]$ to $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. I know that $f$ is differentiable and $f(0)=f(\pi)=0$. Prove that there exists $c$ in $(0,\pi)$ so that $f'(c)=\tan(f(c))$.

I have difficulty in finding $g$ that $g'(x)=f'(x)-\tan(f(x))$ to use the Rolle's theorem. The problem is the function $\tan(x)$ is linked with $f(x)$. Write $g(x)=f(x)+\ln(\cos(f(x))$ is not valid. Help me find the function $g$ and the way to find it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Does that function even exist? The image of a compact set under a continuous function is compact.

Comment: @hff1 I guess it's not *onto*.

Comment: @dfnu that's a good point

Comment: whether my way to solve is wrong or not, if you have another solution beside Rolle theorem, please help me

Answer (score 5):

One can apply Rolle's theorem to the function
$$
 g(x) = e^{-x} \sin(f(x)) \, .
$$
$g$ is differentiable with $g(0) = g(\pi) = 0$, so that $g'(c) = 0$ for some $c \in (0, \pi)$. Since
$$
 g'(x) = e^{-x} \bigl( \cos(f(x)) f'(x) - \sin(f(x))\bigr)
$$
and $\cos(f(x)) > 0$, $g'(c) = 0$ is equivalent to $f'(c) = \tan(f(c))$.

*Remark:* The domain $[0, \pi]$ is irrelevant here, the same proof works for any continuous function $f: [a, b] \to (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ which is differentiable on $(a, b)$ with $f(a) = f(b) = 0$.

Comment: thank you very much. After reading your answer and thinking carefully, I understood this excercise deeply and the way to find a function g

Comment: @NgânKim Since this answered your question, please upvote this and click the checkmark under the voting buttons to accept it as the best answer. For one, it helps other users with the same problem quickly identify the best answer, and it is also a form of thanks to OP (Martin R).